# How to SELECT distinct overall column count over a period and group them by created_at?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT created_at::date, count(DISTINCT sales_events.lead_id) FROM sales_events
WHERE sales_events.user_id = 1023
AND (sales_events.created_at BETWEEN '2018-05-24 07:00:00.000000'
AND '2018-05-31 06:30:00.000000')
group by created_at::date;
```

The Postgres engine only calculates the distinct count of `lead_id` per `created_at::date` value.

I'd like to ensure that all the leads in that time period are unique. Meaning, if a `sales_event` with certain `lead_id` has action 'auto_dial' for Tuesday and then 'incoming_call' for Wednesday, then it should be counted as only 1 and not 2 (as it's currently the case). How to use PSQL to achieve this?

edit: Removed a where condition since that was causing some confusion.

Comment: Is the mysql tag there by accident, as you only mention Postgres in question? If so, please remove the mysql tag.

Comment: Are you saying that "auto_dial" and "incoming_call" are equivalent events for this query?

Comment: Yup, auto_dial, incoming_call, client_call, all denote that a call was made to a lead.

Comment: What about "call_client"? Is that one a different event, then? (Should be counted separately)

Comment: Just edited my comment. All those mean a call was made.

Comment: "ensure that all the leads in that time period are unique". So you want to consider some events as a single one, when they fall into the same "time period". What that would be? A week, a month, a year?

Comment: @Impaler, the time period here refers to the time period mentioned in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can group the leads together first, taking the created_at of the first one for each group, then group it by created_at and count it. I didn't test it, but the following should work.

```
WITH leads AS (
    SELECT
        min(created_at)::DATE AS created_at_date,
        lead_id
    FROM sales_events
    WHERE
       user_id = 1023
       AND action IN ('auto_dial', 'call_client', 'incoming_call')
        AND (created_at BETWEEN '2018-05-24 07:00:00.000000'
            AND '2018-05-31 06:30:00.000000')
    GROUP BY lead_id
)
SELECT
    created_at_date,
    count(*) AS unique_leads
FROM leads
GROUP BY created_at_date;
```

Comment: this might pick up leads whose first action occurred before the time period (on the 23rd for example).  that may be what he's looking for, but I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT created_at::date, count(DISTINCT sales_events.lead_id)
  FROM sales_events s1
 WHERE sales_events.user_id = 1023
   AND (sales_events.created_at BETWEEN '2018-05-24 07:00:00.000000' AND '2018-05-31 06:30:00.000000')
   AND s1.created_at::date = (SELECT min(s2.created_at)::date
                          FROM sales_event s2
                         WHERE s1.lead_id = s2.lead_id)
group by created_at::date;
```

Comment: also, I think T-SQL allows you to specify "having created_at = min(created_at)".  I don't know why this never make it into SQL

Comment: `having created_at = min(created_at)` is valid in SQL and Postgres. However, in this case it's not valid, as `created_at` is not part of the `group by` (but `created_at::date` is), but `having created_at::date = min(created_at::date)`

Comment: I could be wrong., I think what I was thinking is that TSQL allows to you do that when it's not part of the group by.  if it's part of the group by, it would have no effect, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select the first time (during the period) that a the lead is observed:

```
SELECT min_created_at::date, count(*)
FROM (SELECT lead_id, MIN(created_at) as min_created_at
      FROM sales_events se
      WHERE se.user_id = 1023 AND 
            se.created_at BETWEEN '2018-05-24 07:00:00.000000' AND '2018-05-31 06:30:00.000000'
      GROUP BY lead_id
     ) se
GROUP BY min_created_at::date;
```

Note:  This version will count all leads seen during that time period, even if they appeared during earlier time periods.  If you want only new leads, then one approach is to move the time condition to a `WHERE` clause in the outer query.

Comment: I'd be interested to know the database will recreate the entire table as a temp table if you do it this way, consider the case where there are 300,000,000 rows and only three lead types. it's possible that postgres can find the optimal plan.

Comment: @AbdulAhad . . . I don't know what "lead type" has to do with the question.  But yes, this version summarizes the table using whatever method Postgres considers the most efficient method.

Comment: the lead type was edited out of the OP where clause in an edit.  for example type = a, type = b or type = c.  So what I'm thinking is that the subtable you are creating would have 100,000,000 rows.  Postgres may be able to handle it efficiently, and this may be the best way.  I'm interested because this is a common feature that was incorporated into T-SQL with the "having x = min(s)" directive.  That's not available in SQL, so I was wondering if this is the correct way to do it, of if you are supposed to do an internal select joining by and indexed key as in the other answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Shouldn't the outer query reference `min_created_at` instead of `created_at`?